# Call Chrome-Extension Method from within options page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I wrote a chrome extension for a specific website. If the extension is installed and I navigate to that site "example.com", my extension calls the following method:

```
 var search="john";
 $.get("https://www.example.com/complete/search?q="+search, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

That works just fine.

Now I have to call the same method from within the options-page of that extension. When I do that, I receive the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://www.example.com/complete/search?q=John. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

I understand why this happens but have to find a way to get around this. My idea is to trigger the Extension-Script to call the method and then return the results to the options page. I expect, chrome.runtime.sendMessage() isn't help here.

Needless to say: That domain is not hosted by me, so I can't just change the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates it's *not an actual* options page: you're opening it (possibly accidentally) through a local webserver (origin: http://localhost/) instead of opening a page packaged with the extension.

1. You need to add your page (say, `options.html`) to your extension's folder
2. You need to add it to the manifest like `"options_page": "options.html"` or better yet [with `options_ui`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/optionsV2)
3. You need to reload the extension to apply the manifest change
4. You need to open it through the extension, e.g. through `chrome://extensions` or the context menu of your extension's button (if any)

Comment: Gosh. You are right. I accidently opened the file locally. Expected the same behaviour on my options page, though, Cause this  isn't www.example.com either.

Comment: Background page and options page are, from security perspective, the same (privileged origin `chrome-extension://...`). That means host permissions defined in the manifest [override CORS for XHRs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr#requesting-permission).